# pdfpages - smaller space between pages with nup?

Tags: pdfpages

To save space, I have included 4 pages of a pdf file per page in my document using `\includepdf[pages={-}, scale=0.9, nup=2x2, pagecommand={}]{apx/The file.pdf}` but there is a lot of empty space between them and they are needlessly very small and crammed all on the sides (too close to the margins, I would think). Can I modify the spacing and scaling for `nup`? What would be the syntax?

Example - this is how the pages are inserted at the moment:
[image]

And this is what I would like, where the thick red line symbolizes my set margins within the document:
[image]

Comment: Take a look at the `delta` key. It's not entirely clear (to me, at least) what "needlessly very small and crammed all on the sides" mean. A picture?

Comment: I think, you should set smaller the margins of the "apx/The file.pdf"!

Comment: @Werner good point, I added pictures.

Answer (score 2):

As correctly suggested by [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner), the `delta` parameter can be very helpful here. You should indicate both vertical and horizontal spacing between page thumbnails with this parameter. Then if you want more space on the left of the page, you include the `offset` parameter with a non-zero first parameter which stands for a horizontal shift.

Also you won't need the `pagecommand` parameter.

So your code could look like this:

```
\includepdf[pages=-,nup=2x2,scale=0.9,offset=10mm 0mm,delta=2mm 10mm]{apx/The file.pdf}
```